# How to restrict/disable the curl with --insecure or -k, basically, restricting the skipping of certificate validation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I have created a controller with https endpoint in spring boot application.
and I have set the SSL auth mode as WANT.
In this case, when user calls the api using "curl --insecure https://host:port/api" or "curl -k https://host:port/api"
it skips the certificate validation.

I do not want to use the SSL auth mode as NEED and still want to enforce the certificate validation.
basically, in other words, I want to user to restrict the usage of --insecure and -k and want to enforce the user to send the pem file/cert in the curl command.

How could I do it? Any pointers would be helpful.

I want to intercept the calls called by curl --insecure  and block them..
and allow/authenticate the calls which comes with certificate i.e., curl --cacert

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class TestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your springSecurityConfig please

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for responding. I have edited my post along with the code of security config.